# Using Replace to wrap text that start and end with the same thing with some more text

Tags: regex, replace, sublimetext3, sublimetext

Sorry, the title sounds confusing. I am using SublimeText 3. I am looking to wrap a list of items that start and end with the same thing using `Find > Replace...`.

***Example:***

These five items start with `Screenshot` and end with `.png`.

```
Screenshot foo.png
Screenshot bar.png
Screenshot text.png
Screenshot abc.png
Screenshot 123.png
```

Is there a way I can quickly wrap all of these items with "`[[File:`" and "`]]`"?

***Example:***

```
[[File:Screenshot foo.png]]
[[File:Screenshot bar.png]]
[[File:Screenshot text.png]]
[[File:Screenshot abc.png]]
[[File:Screenshot 123.png]]
```

Can it be done with Replace and some regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

search using this regex:

```
(Screenshot.*?[.]png)
```

replace using this regex substitution:

```
[[File: \1]]
```

Output:

```
[[File: Screenshot foo.png]]
[[File: Screenshot bar.png]]
[[File: Screenshot text.png]]
[[File: Screenshot abc.png]]
[[File: Screenshot 123.png]]
```